# Sagepay (opayo) E-commerce Transactions - Clydesdale Bank Mastercard Debit

Tags: opayo

Anyone else having issues with sage-pay (opayo) and clydesdale bank, can't find anything online about other people having issues.

Basically sage-pay (opayo) rejects the payment because of fraud checking rules on the CV2. We are seeing more and more transactions fail because of this. Some people do try an alternate payment but not always.

i've got responses from both sagepay and clydesdale but no eta and surely this is affecting a lot of customers. They both seem to say its each others problem.

From Sage Pay:

> Clydesdale bank have recently stopped returning the CV2 value (3
> digits form the back of the card) security response.
>
> There was no warning or reason for this to stop from Clydesdale and
> our operations team have reached out into the banking community
> contacts for any insights on this but this has then caused our clients
> whose fraud rule base requires a correct CV2 value has seen Clydesdale
> cards fail due to this even though issued in the UK.
>
> Although you could amend your rule base to accommodate this, we will
> always advise the best security possible be in place to protect
> yourself from potential fraud.

From Clydesdale:

> We recently identified that some acquirers/PSPs are sending data,
> relating to our Debit Cards,  through to us incorrectly & I believe
> that Sage is one of the impacted merchants. The data is being sent
> through to us as a Recurring Payment (RP) but with CV2 data.  Our
> processor is approving the transaction subject to all other checks but
> not verifying the CV2 data as it should not be included in a RP
> transaction. As such, when the approval response is received by the
> merchant/acquirer they are rejecting/declining the approved
> authorisation as the CV2 has not been verified. We have been liaising
> with the acquirer on this & they are to get their PSP to make a change
> to ensure that the authorisation data is sent to us correctly. I hope
> that the above information assists and note that we are working with
> the merchants to try and rectify the position, but to date we don’t
> have a timescale for when this may be resolved.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? We are currently seeing the same issue and it's driving us nuts